# Solving 1D telegrapher's equation by reduction to two-dimensional wave equation

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

The solution $w : \mathbb R \times \mathbb R_{+} \to \mathbb R$ of the Cauchy problem
for the telegrapher's equation
$$
 w_{tt} - c^2 w_{xx} + c^2 \lambda^2 w = 0
$$
with
$$
 w(x,0) = 0, \qquad w_t(x,0) = \psi(x)
$$
is given by
$$
 (*) \quad w(x,t) = \frac{1}{2c}\int_{x - ct}^{x+ct} J_0(\lambda s) \psi(y) dy, \quad s^2 = c^2 t^2 - (x-y)^2,
$$
where $J_0$ denotes the $0$-th Bessel function with formula
$$
 J_0(z) = \frac{2}{\pi} \int_0^{\pi/2} \cos(z \sin \theta) d\theta.
$$
Prove (*) with the approach $u(x_1, x_2, t) = \cos(\lambda x_2) w(x_1, t)$ and the solution formula for the Cauchy-Problem of the two-dimensional wave equation.

Comment: seems to be the bounty-comment does not shows the equation, and I cannot edit, so the first equation is: $$ u_{tt}(x,t) - \Delta u(x,t) = 0, \quad u(x,0) = f(x), \quad u_t(x,0) = g(x) $$ and the second formula is $$ u(x,t) = \frac{1}{4\pi t^2} \int\int_{\partial B(x,t)} \frac{g(y)}{\sqrt{t^2 - ||x-y||^2}} dy + \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \int\int_{B(x,t)} \frac{f(y)}{\sqrt{t^2 - ||x-y||^2}} dy$$